# open urls from a file in newtabs in firefox

Tags: bash, firefox, url, for-loop, while-loop

I'm using ubuntu 11.04 and im trying to write a bash script that opens urls from a file each in a new tab with a sleep of 15 or so seconds, the file is 198 lines long and there is one url on each line. i have two potential methods of doing this

method one

```
while read line; do 
    firefox -new-tab "$line"
    sleep 15
done < file
```

method two

```
for line in $(cat file); do
    firefox -new-tab "$line"
    sleep 15
done
```

now both methods seem to give the same result, it opens firefox with the url of the first line and doesn't open any of the other urls until i close the browser, in which case it then opens up firefox with the url on the second line etc...

i have had some success with method one when i remove the sleep command it will try to open all of the urls at once in different tabs

i got the code for method one from: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17659/opening-multiple-urls-from-a-text-file-as-different-tabs-in-firefox-chrome

and i got the code for method two from: http://whileonefork.blogspot.com/2011/02/bash-for-each-line-1-liners.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just try the following code:

```
while read line; do 
    firefox -new-tab "$line" & 2>/dev/null
    sleep 15
done < file
```

Comment: it works perfectly thanks man, but i dont understand the change you made, if its not to much to ask can you explain it

Comment: The & operator puts command in background and free up your terminal.

Comment: and the 2>/dev/null just puts all the output to somewhere it wont clog up?

Comment: @hamsolo474 `2>/dev/null` redirects all error messages from `stderr` to `/dev/null` (actually hides them)

Comment: @maksenov so the & > is a direction of the textual output of the command or solely error messages?

Comment: `2>` redirects `stderr`, `1>` (or just `>`) redirects `stdout` (any non-errors). `&` redirects nothing, it forces background execution of the previous command.

Comment: @maksenov so to sum up & 2>/dev/null sends nothing to /dev/null and errors and execution are no longer in the terminal but because of where we piped it (is piped the correct word) it all now happens in the background

Answer (score 0):

For me both methods work if I just open browser window before starting the script.